# Do Playwright support shared repo?

Tags: shared-libraries

Repo 1 --> Main repo, has all POM related things, More utility functions
Repo 2 --> Imported the Repo 1 and start writing the tests,

But i am keep getting the error from repo 1,
import { expect, Page } from "@playwright/test";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

But if i run the repo1 seperetely that run successfully but when integrate with repo 2 getting this error.

Any help will be really appreciated